# Uncaught (in promise): Error: No Provider for e

Tags: angular

I have a non-public application which was running correctly with `Angular 4.3.6`. I recently updated my package.json to use `Angular 4.4.1` instead of 4.3.6. After upgrading to `Angular 4.4.1`, the front page of the application now loads a blank page instead of my application. When I look in the Javascript Console, it says:

> "Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for e!"

It does not give the file name or line number to any of my code, so I don't know what file is causing the problem. I've attached a screenshot of the developer console. I am new to Angular, so maybe I'm missing something obvious. Is this a documented issue with `Angular 4.4.1`? How do I find which file needs to be updated to find a provider for "e"? I also don't even think that I have a service named with an unmeaningful name like 'e', so I'm guessing that the real name got obfuscated or minified. The error does go away if I downgrade back to `Angular 4.3.6`.

[Screenshot of Javascript Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8V7w.png)

Comment: Depending on how big your App is this may be easy or hard. But that is telling you that one of your services being used is not provided in the encompassing module. I'd run through your services and make sure you are providing them appropriately. Did you make any changes to services?

Comment: @joshrathke - No, I made no other changes besides updating the version in package.json. We manage our code with svn, so I'm quite sure that none of the services changed. Someone else wrote this angular app initially and there are quite a few services, so I was hoping there would be some sort of debug mode or something that I could turn on to at least isolate the problem to a particular component or service.

Comment: Check out the [Change Log](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). At first glance between 4.3.6 and 4.4.1 they made some changes to Animations and fixed a bug with the HTTP module. There are a few other changes, so you might start there.

Comment: If it were me, I'd try to upgrade higher and see if it fixes it as well. Is there a reason you are stopping at 4.4.1?

Comment: @joshrathke - I was hoping to get it working incrementally - I did try upgrading to 5.0 and it wouldn't even compile. I could go back to trying to get it to work with 5.0, but I was thinking it would be easier to move it one version at a time instead of jumping all the way to 5.0. My end goal is to upgrade to 5.0.

Comment: Had the same problem when I migrated to 5.2.8. Have you resolved this? If so, could you share your solution